# Log in user before pay action with Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm trying to force users to login before the pay action with Stripe.  When I add pay to the before_action filter, the user is still prompted to enter their credit card details and it's only when they submit the form are they asked to login.  How do you force the login before the payment form appears, when they actually click the pay button?  Thanks for your help!

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :destroy, :pay]

def pay 
    item = Item.find( params[:id] )
    amount = (item.price * 100).round  
    name = item.name 
    fee = 100
    email = current_user.email 

    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        {
          amount: amount,
          currency: item.user.currency,
          card: params[:token],
          description: name,
          application_fee: fee,
          receipt_email: email, 
         },

      item.user.secret_key
      )

      flash[:success] = "Charged successfully! You will receive an email receipt from Stripe shortly.  In the meantime feel free to browse other items.  Thank you for shopping with a Sewingly seller."

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      error = e.json_body[:error][:message]
      flash[:error] = "Charge failed! #{error}"
    end

    if charge["paid"] == true
      ItemMailer.item_sold(item).deliver_now
      item.update(sold: "true")
      redirect_to item.user
    end 
  end
end
```

pay.coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
  return unless StripeCheckout?

  # Keeps track of whether we're in the middle of processing
  # a payment or not. This way we can tell if the 'closed'
  # event was due to a successful token generation, or the user
  # closing it by hand.
  submitting = false

  payButton = $('.pay-button')
  form = payButton.closest('form')
  indicator = form.find('.indicator').height( form.outerHeight() )

  handler = StripeCheckout.configure
    # The publishable key of the **connected account**.
    key: window.stripePublishableKey
    #key: 'pk_test_MEryapIaDEU6ckqhwuvb7NzU'

    # The email of the logged in user.
    email: window.currentUserEmail

    allowRememberMe: false
    closed: ->
      form.removeClass('processing') unless submitting
    token: ( token ) ->
      submitting = true
      form.find('input[name=token]').val( token.id )
      form.get(0).submit()

  payButton.click ( e ) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    form.addClass( 'processing' )

    handler.open
     name: window.item
     description: window.description
     amount: window.total 
     address: 'true'
     image: window.avatar
```

erb:

```
<%= form_tag pay_item_path do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :token %>
         <button class="btn btn-primary pay-button">Pay now</button>
      <% end %>

        <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js' %>
          <% if logged_in? %>
            <script>
              window.stripePublishableKey = '<%= @item.user.publishable_key %>';
              window.currentUserEmail = '<%= current_user.email %>';
              window.payPath = '<%= pay_item_path( @item.user ) %>';
              window.total =  '<%= item_total %>';
              window.avatar = '<%= @item.user.avatar_url %>';
              window.item = '<%= @item.name %>'
            </script>
          <% else %>
            <script>
              window.stripePublishableKey = '<%= @item.user.publishable_key %>';
              window.payPath = '<%= pay_item_path( @item.user ) %>';
              window.total =  '<%= item_total %>';
              window.avatar = '<%= @item.user.avatar_url %>';
              window.item = '<%= @item.name %>'
            </script>
```

Comment: What is the controller/action used for the view where they input their credit card details? It certainly appears that the `pay` method assumes that the credit card details have already been input.